# Clean Architecture UI layer containing Entity Framework Core Reference

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-5, clean-architecture

I'm working on a .Net 5 project I have used Clean Architecture pattern . When I handle concurrency I need to add a EFCore reference to the Web project as below. Is that correct to add EFCore reference to the Web project in Clean Architecture pattern. DbUpdateConcurrencyException Need EFCore reference.

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> EditSubmit(EditProductViewModel editProductViewModel)
    {
        try
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View("../Product/Edit", editProductViewModel);
            }

            await _productService.UpdateProduct(editProductViewModel);
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View("../Product/Edit", new EditProductViewModel());
        }
        catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException ex)
        {
            string message = "Product has been changed by another user please go to Product List";
            _log.LogError(message + ":" + ex.ToString());
            return View("../Product/Edit", editProductViewModel);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string message = "Product update failed";
            _log.LogError(message + ":" + ex.ToString());
            return View("../Product/Edit", editProductViewModel);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that this is not correct for Clean Architecture. I believe you should create a custom `Exception`, perhaps in your `Application` layer, and throw that up to the UI/API layer instead. If you keep a dependency on the EF Core package in the API, in the event that you ever decide to change your persistence mechanism (e.g. not using Entity Framework), you would have to also change your UI/API layer with 1) a new package reference, and 2) a new exception type.